# Can't bind to 'ngIf'

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

Can't bind to `ngIf` since it isn't a known property

```
<AddWrkFrcePopUp *ngIf="showWrkFrcePop === true" (closeWrfFrcePop)="_closeWrkFrcePop()">
</AddWrkFrcePopUp>
```

Comment: This is most often caused by a missing imports in your Angular module. Can you post what your angular module looks like? (The one that declares AddWrkFrcePopUp)

Comment: Also, please, You would greatly improve the readability of your code by adding those two missing `o`s and `up`, and removing this useless `=== true`: `*ngIf="showWorkForcePopup"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RC5 then import this:

```
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

and be sure to import CommonModule from the module that is providing your component.

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [CommonModule],
   declarations: [MyComponent]
   ...
 })
class MyComponentModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked with that, no need   fro BrowserModule in my case

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
```

and add CommonModule to the Imports

```
 imports: 
  [
    CommonModule
  ],
```